# Align Bootstrap 4 Button with other content of the page in Angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 where Buttons are not aligned ....[image]

I fix this issue writing some css

```
.btn-success, .btn-danger, .btn-primary {
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: -15px;
```

}

[image]

**Html**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<form>
  <div class="row ml-auto">
    <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
      <label for="amount">Amount</label>
      <input type="number" id="amount" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

I use bootstrap classes ml-auto, float-right but nothing solve my problem. I believe there is better way of solving this problem ...

Comment: Which buttons do you want to align exactly? The three action buttons are aligned. They simply have to have some margin on either sides. Do you want the result of your seconds image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
class="text-right"
```

And Follow the rules of the [Bootstrap grid.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works) From the docs.

> "Rows are wrappers for columns... In a grid layout, content must be
>   placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of
>   rows."

```
<container>
  <row>
    <col-12>
      <card/>
    </col>
    <col-12>
      <card/>
    </col>
    <col-12>
      <card/>
    </col>
  </row>
</container>
```

or,

```
<container>
  <row>
    <col-12>
      <card/>
    </col>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col-12>
      <card/>
    </col>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col-12>
      <card/>
    </col>
  </row>
</container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add a parent flex-container and add the CSS propriety `justify-content: spacebetween`, like this:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<form>
  <div class="row ml-auto">
    <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
      <label for="amount">Amount</label>
      <input type="number" id="amount" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-container col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```